# How can i go through certain amount of numbers, storing the amount of steps it took to reach certain point? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

**Context:**
I'm storing the day of the week the user made the last purchase on my website. The function `getDay()` returns a number corresponding to that weeks day, beeing `0` as Sunday and `6` as Saturday. So a purchase made today, 07/14/2022, will store the number `4`, Thursday.

**Problem:**
Knowing the date and day of the week the user made the purchase, i want it to know, base on the todays date, how many days will take to reach the weeks day, which the user made that purchase!

**Clarifying:**
Exemple - If a user made a purchase on day of the week `0`, sunday, based on todays date, 07/14/2022, so number `4`, **how many days will take to reach day `0`**? Adding number by number, we know will take 3 days, but how can i calculate dynamically???

**More Examples:**
Find how many days will take to reach day `3`, todays beeing day `4`. So we need to go through day 5,6,0,1,2, so `5`

Find how many days will take to reach day `2`, todays beeing day `6`. So we need to go through day 0, 1 and 2, so `3`

Comment: what, if you have already sunday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a delta of to and from day plus seven and takes the remainder by seven.

```js
const
    getDays = (from, to) => (7 + to - from) % 7;

console.log(getDays(0, 0)); // 0
console.log(getDays(6, 0)); // 1
console.log(getDays(4, 3)); // 5 6 0 1 2 3 -> 6
console.log(getDays(6, 2)); // 0 1 2 -> 3
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Cool, but the day the user will made a purchase can be any day of the week, so if i understood your logic, 7 can be changed to a variable corresponding to the weeks day the user made the purchase????

Comment: do you have some examples? please add additional information to the question.

Comment: Your answer is on the right track but I really need it to be dynamic not restricted to Sunday

Comment: Find how many days will take to reach day 2, todays beeing day 6. So we need to go through day 0, 1 and 2, so 3 need to be the result
@nina-scholz